# python subprocess run works with single string but not list of strings

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm trying to initiate a command-line program with command-line options from my Python script using the *run* method from the *subprocess* module.

My command is defined as a list of strings specifying the program and options as follows (where `pheno_fp` and `construction_fp` are strings representing file paths in my system and `exe` is a string representing the file path to the program I'm running):

```
    step1_cmd = [exe, 
                "--step 1",
                "--p " + pheno_fp,
                "--b 1000",
                "--o " + construction_fp + "dpw_leaveout"]
```

**Not working** - When I try the following, the program I want to run is started but the command I've specified is interpreted incorrectly because the program exits with an error saying "specify output file path with --o flag":

```
    test1 = subprocess.run(step1_cmd)
```

**Working** - When I try the following, the program executes correctly, meaning all arguments are interpreted as intended:

```
    test1 = subprocess.run(" ".join(step1_cmd), shell=True)
```

If I understood the documentation correctly, the former approach is the recommended usage but I can't understand why it's not working. I'm pretty sure it's formatted the same as the examples in the documentation so I'm a bit stumped. Any ideas?

Comment: try to separate each parm with a comma if you want to use it as list

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Split each parameter with its value, like so:

```py
step1_cmd = [exe, 
             "--step",
             "1",
             "--p",
             str(pheno_fp),  # if it isn't a string already
             "--b",
             "1000",
             "--o",
             str(construction_fp) + "dpw_leaveout"
]
```

Because when passing a list of parameters, each part is separated with a space, both options and their values

Comment: You've got some typos there, and I think all your arguments need to be strings.

Comment: Right, forgot about that. Updated the answer

Answer (score 2):

The explanation for this behavior is [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments):

> args is required for all calls and should be a string, or a sequence
> of program arguments. Providing a sequence of arguments is generally
> preferred, as it allows the module to take care of any required
> escaping and quoting of arguments (e.g. to permit spaces in file
> names).

Example: the sequence

```
l = ['ls', '-l tmp']
```

gives an error

```
subprocess.run(l)                                                                                                                                                      
ls: illegal option --
```

This is because `subprocess` (which is a call to `Popen`) is trying to run `ls "-l tmp"` .

The correct way to define a sequence of arguments is by separating them so that they can be quoted correctly

```
subprocess.run(['ls', '-l', 'tmp'])
```